Advanced Installer showing update dialogue of my application repeatedly
I am trying to learn Advanced Installer Automatic Update feature. The Updater of my XYZ application showing update dialogue for every 5 minutes and showing XYZ is up to date. But I want after launching XYZ application it will check update without showing update dialogue and if it finds any newer version of XYZ application only then it will show the update dialogue.



What I need to do to get my expected behavior.

You should call the Updater.exe with the /silent switch. The Updater searches silently for updates at the interval specified in the Configuration dialog - "Check Frequency" field (Updater).
If the check frequency has passed and updates are found, the Updater will be launched with full UI and display them to the user. Otherwise, it will exit immediately. The silent switch has the purpose of hiding the Updater messages which inform that it is searching for updates and that no updates have been found.
Since you want to fire the task every 5 min, you should set the update frequency check to 0.
Check the Updater command line switches article for details.
See the following sample project, maybe it will help you Install updates without elevation, automatically at user logon.
